# Can I pass a table name into a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that I want to use but I need to pass the table name into it.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[STT_Card_Entry_Temp_Write] 
@CARD_NO as VarChar(20),
@tablename as table
AS
BEGIN
Update live.scheme.sttakedm
    set adjustment_quantit= (TM.expected_quantity-TM.counted)*-1,

        take_sign=case left((TM.expected_quantity-TM.counted),1)
                  when  '-' then '+'
                  else  '-'
                  end,

        status=''

        from        live.scheme.sttakedm (nolock) stt
        inner join  @tablename TM (NOLOCK) 
        on          TM.card_number=@CARD_NO
        and         TM.sequence_number=stt.sequence_number collate database_default
        and         TM.product_code=stt.product_code collate database_default
        and         stt.kind = 'B'

truncate table @tablename

END
```

This is my code that currently does not work.

Comment: you will need to use dynamic sql

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific, perhaps it looks like <sql-server>.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can phrase this as:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[STT_Card_Entry_Temp_Write] (
    @CARD_NO as VarChar(20),
    @tablename as table
) AS
BEGIN
    declare @sql nvarchar(max);

    set @sql = '
Update live.scheme.sttakedm
    set adjustment_quantit = (TM.expected_quantity - TM.counted) * -1,
        take_sign = (case left((TM.expected_quantity - TM.counted), 1)
                         when ''-'' then ''+'' else ''-''
                     end),

        status = ''''

    from live.scheme.sttakedm stt join
         @tablename TM
         on TM.card_number = @CARD_NO and
            TM.sequence_number = stt.sequence_number collate database_default and
            TM.product_code = stt.product_code collate database_default and
            stt.kind = 'B'
';

    set @sql = replace(@sql, '@tablename', quotename(@tablename));

    exec sp_executesql @sql,
                       N'@CARD_NO varchar(20)',
                       @CARD_NO=@CARD_NO;

    set @sql = 'truncate table @tablename';

    set @sql = replace(@sql, '@tablename', quotename(@tablename));

    exec sp_executesql @sql;
END;
```

I would strongly advise you from using `truncate table` in dynamic SQL.  You can really cause some problems.

If you are truncating the table, then why not just have a canonical table name used for passing values in?  Or -- better yet -- create a table type so you can pass in the table directly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention the database engine you're using, but the feature you need is called "dynamic SQL"; Google is your friend.

I'd be *very* nervous about allowing `truncate table @tablename` in dynamic SQL, though - it's really inviting disastrous bugs.